# Microsoft Graph API Returning 401 Despite Having Required Scope & Account Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have an API that utilizes a service account (work account type - not a personal account) to do the following:

1. Using our Service Account, Gets a Token from our Azure AD with scopes: `["user.read", "User.Read.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All", "ChatMessage.Send", "Chat.Create", "Chat.ReadWrite"]`
2. Use that token to upload a file to our SharePoint. -> This succeeds
3. Use that token to Get the UserID from email (UserPrincipalNames map in our AD, so this is not a concern) -> This succeeds
4. Use that token to Create a new chat/Get the existing chat between the user & our service account (using `POST /v1.0/chats`) -> This returns 401 Unauthorized
5. Send the message from service account to user (using `POST /v1.0/chats/{chatID returned from step 4}/messages`)

The users we are attemping to send these messages to are all in our Azure AD.

We are unsure how the previous requests with this token succeed, and the Create/Get Chat fails with a 401. We have confirmed that the token is correctly being set in the authorization header (we are using the exact same process as the previous requests).

Also, we have these API Permissions set in our Azure AD for this application:

[image]

If we use jwt.io to examine the token, we do see the scope is set in the token being set in the Authorization header of the request.

[image]

Additionally the audience is set to Graph API:

[image]

Here is our code:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OurAPI.Helpers.IHelpers;
using OurAPI.Models;
using OurAPI.Repositories.IRepositories;
using System.Text;

namespace OurAPI.Repositories
{
    public class TeamsRepository : ITeamsRepository
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly ITokenHelper _tokenHelper;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;


        public TeamsRepository(IConfiguration config, ITokenHelper tokenHelper, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _config = config;
            _tokenHelper = tokenHelper;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<object> GeneratePDFAndSendToTeams(TeamsPostRequest request)
        {
            // Authenticate
            string token = await _tokenHelper.GetMicrosoftGraphAccessToken();

            // Convert from Base64 to Memory Stream
            var file = GeneratePDF(request.Base64);

            // Upload PDF to SharePoint
            var sharepointFile = await UploadFile(file, request, token);

            // Get UserID from email
            var user = await GetUser(request.User, token);

            // Create a new chat with service account or Retrieve Chat if already exists
            var chat = await GetChat(user.Id, token);

            // Post to chat between service account and requesting user
            var chatMessage = await SendToTeams(sharepointFile, chat, token);

            
            return chat;
        }

        public async Task<object> GetChats(string token)
        {
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/serviceaccount@domain.com/chats");
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents);

            return chats;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUser(string userEmail, string token)
        {
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + userEmail);
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(contents);

            return user;
        }

        public async Task<Chat> GetChat(string userID, string token)
        {
            var chatRequest = new Models.ChatRequest(userID);
            chatRequest.ChatType = "oneOnOne";


            var chatMember = new ChatMember();
            chatMember.Type = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember";
            chatMember.Roles = new List<string>() { "owner" };
            chatMember.User = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{userID}')";

            var serviceAccount = new ChatMember();
            serviceAccount.Type = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember";
            serviceAccount.Roles = new List<string>() { "owner" };
            serviceAccount.User = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{OurServiceAccountID}')";

            chatRequest.Members = new List<ChatMember> { chatMember, serviceAccount };


            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats");
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chatRequest);
            request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var chat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Chat>(contents);

            return chat;
        }

        // POST /chats/{chat-id}/messages
        public async Task<ChatMessage> SendToTeams(DriveItem sharePointFile, Chat chat, string token)
        {
            var chatMessageRequest = new Models.ChatMessageRequest(sharePointFile);

            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/" + chat.Id + "/messages");
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chatMessageRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var chatMessageResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatMessage>(contents);


            return chatMessageResponse;
        }

    public async Task<DriveItem> UploadFile(MemoryStream file, TeamsPostRequest teamsPostRequest, string token)
        {
            string siteID = "{ourSiteID}";

            string PTparentID = "{ourParentID}"
            
            string custNameForFile = teamsPostRequest.CustomerName;
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, _config["Graph:BaseUrl"] + "/sites/" + siteID + "/drive/items/" + PTparentID + ":/" + custNameForFile + teamsPostRequest.PickTicketNo + ".pdf:/content");
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
            request.Content = new StreamContent(file);


            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var driveItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriveItem>(contents);

            return driveItem;
        }

        private static MemoryStream GeneratePDF(string base64)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            MemoryStream ms = new(bytes);

            return ms;
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is the request we are making to get the token:

```
public async Task<string> GetMicrosoftGraphAccessToken()
{
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ourTenantID}/";
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "User.Read.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All", "ChatMessage.Send", "Chat.Create", "Chat.ReadWrite" };
    IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_config["AzureAD:ClientId"])
                                        .WithAuthority(authority)
                                        .Build();

    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in _config["MicrosoftGraph:Password"])
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, _config["MicrosoftGraph:Username"], securePassword)
                                        .ExecuteAsync();


    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

We are at a lose for what could be going on here. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have an authentication issue.  Do google search for "msdn authentication".

Comment: @jdweng your comment does not contribute anything useful to this question. Additionally, I now need to correct you for future visitors to this question. It would be "MSAL Authentication" that you would want to google, not MSDN.

Comment: Both MSDN and MSAL are Microsoft.  You will find lots of Info using my search.

Comment: I know that. If visitors to this question want information relevant to this question, they would search MSAL authentication, not MSDN authentication as you originally stated.

Comment: Try it my way, you will like results.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to see the details of the token.

Copy the token, paste it at https://jwt.ms and inspect the details.

You’re probably interested in the scopes.

I guess the account you’re using should be one of the participants of the chat, this cannot be used to create chats between other users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post you seem to be doing the right request.